# Powerpoint VBA Bold Font

Tags: vba, fonts, powerpoint

I have created a multiple choice test (using VBA) to use with a training module.  Both have been created in PowerPoint 2013.  At the end of the test, there is a page that will be printed with the results and the answers given by the student taking the test.  The problem I am having is this:  I need to somehow distinguish the incorrect answers from the correct answers.  I want to make the font of the incorrect answers shown on the results page bold and I cannot figure out how to do that.  I am in no way fluent in VBA and most of what I have done, I have found through searches on the internet.  Here is the "Wrong answer" section of the VBA that I have:

```vba
Sub WrongAnswer()

    Dim thisQuestionNum As Long

    thisQuestionNum = _
        ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex - 1
    If qAnswered(thisQuestionNum) = False Then
        numIncorrect = numIncorrect + 1
    End If
    qAnswered(thisQuestionNum) = True
    MsgBox "Incorrect. "
    ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Next
End Sub
```

Basically what it does, is tell the student whether or not the button they clicked on was correct or incorrect and then stores the answer and number correct/incorrect to a printable slide.  Do I need to create an entirely new sub section to make the font show up as  bold?  Or can I add it into my Wrong Answer section?  What code do I need in order to make it work?

Comment: What text do you want to make bold?  It's not clear from your example.  Assuming you have a reference to a shape containing the text, then oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = True will do it.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg - The example above is what I used to count correct or incorrect answers (I have one for Right Answers, too). It also pops up a message box that says correct or incorrect.  All the answers (correct or incorrect) are saved and will appear on a printable slide.  I want to make the wrong answers the student selects appear bold on the printable slide. Thank you!

Comment: OK; show us the code you're using to create the printable slide and add text to it.  Or do you not know how to do that?

Comment: @Steve - Sub PrintablePage()
    Dim printableSlide As Slide
    
    Set printableSlide = _
        ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(Index:=53, _
        Layout:=ppLayoutTwoColumnText)
    printableSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
        "Results for " & userName & "." & _
                "  You got " & numCorrect & " out of " & _
        numCorrect + numIncorrect & ". Press the Print Results button." & Chr$(13)
    printableSlide.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20

Comment: For i = 1 To 24
        printableSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
            printableSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text & _
            "Question " & i & ": " & answer(i) & Chr$(13)
        Next i
    printableSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 9
    For i = 25 To 50
        printableSlide.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
            printableSlide.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Text & _
            "Question " & i & ": " & answer(i) & Chr$(13)
        Next i
    printableSlide.Shapes(3).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 9

Comment: Sorry for the two posts.  There is also a print button, but that doesn't really  have anything to do with what I'm needing

Answer (score 0):

've quoted back just the relevant part for the first column of text; the same changes will apply to the second column as well:

Dim oRng as TextRange

```
For i = 1 To 24 

' Instead of this:
    printableSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _ printableSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text & _ "Question " & i & ": " & answer(i) & Chr$(13) 

' Do this:
' This just adds the answer, to keep it simple to understand for now. 
' You can add the "Question: " stuff later:
Set oRng = printableSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter (vbcrlf & answer(1))
With oRng
   .Font.Size = 9
   .Font.Bold = True
    ' etc
End with
Next i 

printableSlide.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 9
```

Comment: I will give that a try.  Thanks for your help!